# Como obtener las sílabas de una palabra

Tags: kotlin, algoritmos, aplicación-movil

Buen día, estoy intentando crear una aplicación en donde tengo que tomar las silabas de una palabra, hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente:

```
val syllables       = mutableListOf<String>()
val vocals          = setOf('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U')
val rlh             = setOf('r', 'l', 'h', 'R', 'L', 'H')
val numSyllables    = 0
var editableWord    = word
var pendingSyllable = ""

if (word[0] in vocals){
    pendingSyllable = word[0].toString()
    word = word.drop(1)
    println(syllables)
}

var i = 0
do {
    if (word[i] in vocals){
        if (word[i-1] in rlh && i-1 != 2){
            syllables += pendingSyllable + word.substring(0, i-2)
            word = word.drop(i-2)
            i = 3
        } else {
            syllables += pendingSyllable + word.substring(0, i-1)
            word = word.drop(i-1)
            i = 2
        }
        pendingSyllable = ""
    }
    i++
} while (word.length >= i)

syllables += word
println("Estas son mis silabas $syllables")

return syllables
```

Aún no está completo, pero hasta donde está ya debería sacar algunas sílabas bien, y algunas palabras como instrumento o computadora las saca bien, el problema es que algunas otras palabras no.

El algoritmo lo saqué de https://construyendoachispas.blog/2017/07/26/lenguaje-separar-palabras-en-silabas/

Mi pregunta es, alguien sabe algo que se pueda hacer o algún algoritmo o código para sacar las sílabas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La silabización en español es algo más compleja de lo que se sugiere en el enlace que pones en la pregunta, pues en ese algoritmo no se están teniendo en cuenta las tildes, que pueden jugar un papel importante al deshacer un diptongo. Por ejemplo compara **"recién"** (dos sílabas: re-cién, debido al diptongo) con **"rocíen"** (tres sílabas: ro-cí-en, debido a que al estar acentuada la vocal débil se deshace el diptongo).

Un algoritmo más preciso (y complejo) lo tienes descrito en el artículo [Automatic syllabification for Spanish using lemmatization and derivation to solve the prefix’s prominence issue](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S095741741300451X?via%3Dihub), y está implementado en un par de librerías:

- [Python](https://github.com/nur-ag/syltippy) Si conoces python esta implementación puede servirte de guía para hacer la tuya, pues es fácil de leer (dentro de lo que cabe, ya que el algoritmo es complejo)
- [Java](https://github.com/vic/silabas4j) Ya que estás usando Kotlin, es posible que puedas usar directamente esta implementación Java.

Comment: Me fue útil tu respuesta, pero también me ayudó este algoritmo https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-24630-5_49

Answer (score 1):

No entendí bien tu pregunta, pero bueno responderé lo mejor posible.

Podés hacer lo siguiente:

Puedes contar todas las vocales de las sílabas de las palabras, pero, solamente, cuando la sílaba de la palabra no tenga diptongo/triptongo.

Por ejemplo:

Supongamos, que queremos separar el sílabas la palabra "fuego", entonces para separarla, hacemos lo siguiente:

- Contamos todas las vocales (en este caso hay 3).
- Restamos las vocales por las cantidades de diptongos/triptongo que hay (en este caso, hay un diptongo: "ue").
- Finalmente, lo que nos sobre será la cantidad de sílabas.

Entonces, el resultado de las sílabas de la palabra "fuego", serían: 2 ("Fue-go").

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder @Elblack Ninja , pero creo que eso solamente sirve para saber la cantidad de sílabas, lo que yo necesito es separar la palabra en sílabas.

Comment: @Fernando Bueno, ¡eso es aún más fácil! Pero ya no valdrá la pena, ya que alguien te respondió tu pregunta.