# Separar en silabas una cadena y ponerlas en una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Estoy buscando crear una función que me tome una cadena ingresada por el usuario y me devuelva una lista con sus silabas.

```
def dameSilabas(candidata): #recibe la pal que ing el usuario y devuelve una lista con sus silabas
    silabas=[]
```

Pero tengo problemas en imaginarme como hacer que me separe por vocales, tendria que idenfiticar cunado hay una vocal y guardar esa pos y su anterior? Espero que me puedan dar una mano

Comment: Relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/411205/7123

Comment: Aquí tienes un algoritmo en python en el que te puedes basar: https://github.com/amunozf/separasilabas

Answer (score 2):

Esta creo que es una pregunta más de gramática que de programación. Para separar en sílabas en español hay algunas reglas bastante claras.
Hay vocales abiertas y cerradas. Las abiertas son A, E, O. Las cerradas son I, U. Si cualquier vocal tiene tilde se vuelve abierta. Ahora bien, si dos abiertas se juntan hay un hiato, es decir, se separan las sílabas. Por ejemplo: MAÍZ. La A es abierta y la Í, como tiene tilde, tambien es abierta. Se separaría MA-ÍZ.
En otro caso (2 cerradas o una abierta y una cerrada), es un diptongo y no se separa. Como GUAR-DAR.
Algunos casos a tomar en cuenta, la H va junto a la 2da silaba, como A-HO-RA. La Y si suena como I es cerrada como la I, por ejemplo: U-RU-GUAY.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo mejor seria usar una herramienta para que te ayude, como propone abulafia en los comentarios, sin embargo tu problema me resulto interesante y decidí hacerlo, mi programa no separa las silabas de acuerdo a **Todas** las reglas gramaticales y aun tiene un pequeño fallo, pero creo que es bueno para entender como hacerlo y guiarte.

```py
def dameSilabas(cadena):
  silabas = []

  for l in cadena:
      if l in vocales:
          actual = cadena.index(l)
          if actual != 0:
              ant = cadena[actual-1] 

          #verificamos si la anterior y actual letra son vocales
          #no entra a este if
          if ant in vocales and l in vocales:
              if len(cadena)<actual+1:
                silabas[-1] += l

          elif cadena[actual] in vocales:
              silaba = cadena[: actual+1]

              silabas.append(silaba)
              cadena = cadena.split(silaba)
              print(cadena,silaba) #vemos como se va separando
              cadena = cadena[1]
  print(silabas)
```

**Probamos**

```py
dameSilabas("mariposa") 
#resultado -> ['ma', 'ri', 'po', 'sa']

dameSilabas("hola")
#resultado -> ['ho','la']

#error
dameSilabas("matemáticas") 
#resultado -> ['ma', 'te', 'máti', 'ca']

#error
dameSilabas("matríz") 
#resultado -> ['ma']
```

Esto es lo que pude hacer, de forma *"natural"* sin módulos ni algoritmos de otros, como dije no es muy bueno, y lo mejor seria un apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar una librería de Python llamada Pyphen:

```
pip install pyphen
```

Para utilizarlo sería:

```
import pyphen
a = pyphen.Pyphen(lang='es')
print(a.inserted('mariposa'))
```

Aquí tienes la documentación: https://doc.courtbouillon.org/pyphen